# sharing folders in virtual box

Tags: linux, mount, virtualbox, virtual-machine, file-sharing

I'm trying to run a Linux Mint guest inside a Linux Mint host(both 64-bit). I've installed Guest Additions etc. But I'm not able to access the shared folder.

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf kernel /media/sf_kernel
```

gives the error:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

Please help me debug and find the solution to this problem.

I install the virtual box guest additions( from the vmware), dkms(both host and guest), build-essentials(both). In fact, I installed a lot of packages. Is the any list which can get the shared folder service to function appropriately?

Comment: it would be helpful to list which addons you installed and where.